# How to make windows 8 recovery disk?

Tags: windows-8, compact-disc

I have a desktop with dual booting windows 8(original) and ubuntu 10.04. If I need to format my C drive containing windows 8 , then  windows 8 will be lost. So I want to make a recovery disk such that I can get back windows 8 (original). How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [system image to backup the complete Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8956-system-image-create-windows-8-a.html). Open the control panel, go to Win7 backup and select "Create a system image"

[image]

Now select where you want to store the backup:

[image]

and what to include:

[image]

At the end of the wizard you can create a recovery image if you don't have a DVD.

[image]